# Wanting to power small audio amp toy with usb power bank

Tags: voltage, step-down

It uses 3 AA batteries but I'm looking to determine if I can either just use the usb 5v or find a plug & play method to adjust the voltage down half a volt.  I say plug and play because while I'm ok with soldering the usb output leads to the power input, I don't think I have the skill to add a resistor in that cable line or a board.  It's going into a helmet that already has a small power bank installed, so the weight and size of the 3 AA batteries is what I'm trying to eliminate.

Item shown here amazon.com/dp/B000XEYZFY/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_xok.BbKTNHYBV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fresh no-load voltage for alkaline cells can be as high as 1.63V (and higher at elevated temperatures), see [data1](https://goughlui.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/GABT-Statistical-Summary.pdf) or [data2](https://rightbattery.com/38-1-5v-aa-energizer-industrial-alkaline-battery-tests/), or up to 1.65 V according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery). Therefore 3 of fresh alkaline cells in series can make about 4.95 V initially. The audio amplifier is likely tolerant to this kind of voltages, with some +15-20% room, so a +5V stable supply should be just fine. I see no danger to supply the device straight with +5V source.